# How to migrate a proxy NPM repository in Nexus 3?

Tags: javascript, npm, nexus, devops

I have a Nexus 3 installation with these NPM repos defined:

- npm-all (group)
- npm-internal (hosted)
- npmjs-org (proxy)

I would like to be able to populate the npm proxy repository on an Internet connected machine, and then migrate it to a Nexus Server running on a disconnected machine.  Nexus 3 has a Task to backup/restore the entire underlying Orient database, but I can't find a way to do it for a specific repository.  My goal is to have a npm proxy repo that's populated with NPM packages I need, in an offline environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do this with any built in mechanism. Your best bet is to publish all packages you need to a hosted repository or alternatively just have the proxy repo and server connected to the internet during provisioning but take it offline afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [npm](https://github.com/rluvaton/nexus-migration-util) tool.

Using this tool download the artifacts from the repositories and upload them in the offline server

> Disclaimer, I’m the author of this package